# Should URL params and request params be stored in the Request object

Tags: object-oriented, php, http-request

> Is it acceptable if GET parameters don't reside in the Request object, but in the URL?

---

I am writing a small library in PHP, which represents the Request/Response as different entities and at moment there are three objects related to representing the request:

- `Query`: Represents the GET parameters in the request. Is injected in the URL object
- `URL`: Represents the full URL
- `Request`: At the moment is only aware of the URL object.

Currently I am storing the request body in the Request object (and I cannot think of a more appropriate place) and with the current implementation the signature which I have to use to get a parameter is:

```
$requestObject->getUrl()->getParam($some-get-param); // For GET params
$requestObject->param($some-post-param); // For others
```

Which I think does not break the *Single Responsibility* paradigm as:

```
$requestObject->getParam($some-get-param); // Or..
$requestObject->fetchGetParam($some-get-param);
```

Comment: According to the [RFC for RLs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), the query parameters are part of the URL, so using `$request->getURL()->getParam(x)` is fully correct.

Comment: would you consider making this an answer so I could accept?

Comment: There are more aspects to consider in the design and I don't have the time to write that up in a proper answer right now.

Comment: Am I missing something? What's wrong with just using `$_GET['paramName']`?

Comment: A lot of time and effort has been put into PSR-7, have a look: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/

Comment: @localheinz note that the question is pre-PSR7. As well this question was for implementing it in a project of mine as it was not fully finished, as well note that the GET parameters are not covered in the PSR